# Is there any case for a mov and mp4 containers be interchangeable?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, ffprobe

The question migh be silly,
But I got the following situation.

I have a bunch of MOV video files from some clients, I was going to convert them to MP4 to be able to run on a browser.
However, when I just tried to open it on the browser it worked fine, both in Firefox and Chrome.

When I run ffmpeg on one of those files I get fhe following:

```
ffmpeg -i MyVideo.mov -hide_banner
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MyVideo.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2011-06-27 19:53:07
    Duration: 00:10:10.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10234 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 10103 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 5k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-06-27 19:53:07
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
   Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-06-27 19:53:07
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
```

When running ffprobe to check the container I get a bunch of outputs:

```
[FORMAT]
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
[/FORMAT]
```

What exactly does this means? All those containers are interchangeable?
If not, why browsers are able to read this file?

Firefox version: 59.0.2
Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MP4 container is an ISO format and was derived from the Quicktime format. FFmpeg has a single module (demuxer) to parse all the extensions mentioned in the format_name string you pasted. For safety's sake, it's recommended to remux MOVs to MP4 since you shouldn't be relying on the laxity of browsers.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -c copy -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

Doing this operation will also help you validate whether all the streams are acceptable in a MP4 e.g. LPCM audio streams are acceptable in MOV but not MP4.